# Backbone create sending no data to server in Http Post?

Tags: backbone.js, backbone.js-collections

I have a very simple model called "gameModel" and a collection "gamesCollection" shown below. When I try to create a new game in the collection it sends a post to the server but that post has no data in it. Does any know what is going on?

```
//The relevant code
var game = new gameModel();
game.gameId = id;
gamesCollection.create(game);

...........
//The Collection 
define([
  'jQuery',
  'Underscore',
  'Backbone',
  'collections/common/mixin',
  'models/game',
  'config/restresource'
    ], function($, _, Backbone, collectionMixin, gameModel, restDomain){
    var gamesCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        url: (new restDomain()).getGamesRoot(),
        model: gameModel,
        initialize: function(){
            _.extend(this.__proto__, collectionMixin);
        },

        parse: function(resp, xhr) {
            var games = [];
            for(i=0;i<resp.length;i++){
                games.push(new gameModel({gameId: resp[i].gameId}));
            }
            return games;
        },
    });

    return new gamesCollection;
});
```

Comment: Are you overloading `Backbone.sync` or setting a `Collection.sync`?

Comment: @rudolph9 No, everything should be default

Comment: I was able to get save to work by calling save on the model directly, which puts the Game ID in the URL but would still like to get it working through the list

Comment: Could you post the model code as well?

Comment: As well as the `collectionMixin` code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
gamesCollection.create({"id":id});
```

`Backbone.Collection.create` accepts attributes as the first argument, *not* a model... If a model is successfully created, returned is a model.  So, you may want to implement it like the following if you still wish to use the `game` model object.

```
var game = gamesCollection.create({"id":id});
```

Comment: Why not `gamesCollection.create(game.toJSON())`?

Comment: @Lukas because then you have two model objects with the same data... if you need to _add_ an existing model to a collection then use [`Backbone.Collection.add`](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-add).

Comment: My problem was that I thought the intent of create was to "create" a model client side and save it to the server.